# Convert website to webapplication (User Controls)

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, web-applications, user-controls, web

I'm developing a website in asp.net and now I need to convert it to a webapplication.

I created a new project with a new webapplication template and copy me files. I did a right click in the sollution and convert to webapplication and it worked fine, the vs2010 has created a design.vb files for each webform and it's good.

But, there are some webforms that uses some user controls and this user control doesn't created the declation in design.vb. I'd like to know if is there any way to fix the declations in webform to a my desing file to be used in code-behine ???

Thanks

Comment: Did you do the very last step on converting the classes from this page? http://bartwullems.blogspot.com/2011/02/converting-website-project-to-web.html

Comment: Yes, I did this steps following the MSDN link. Are there other suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can right click on each user control and select `Convert To Web Application` (or something like that) individually to generate the designer files.

Comment: Yes, I did this, and it works but not completely. My user controls need to be declated on design files.

Comment: You mentioned that you did it to the whole site. My point was that you can also do it for each individual ascx file. Have you tried converting each file by itself?

Answer (score -1):

There is **no** easy way to do this through **VS**. You can alternatively try **ReSharper's Adjust Namespace** functionality.

Comment: Please provide more context or an example with your answer. Otherwise, make a comment.